# How to simulate multiple login and request on mobile app?

Tags: jmeter, mobile, mobile-applications

Just wanted to ask if there is a possibility to simulate multiple logins and request(e.g.100 users) on a mobile app?

1. Is it possible using on JMeter? If Yes, How?
2. Are there any other specific tools are available to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Jmeter to check performance of the module as well wants to check System Integration testing follow below process it's quite simple.

Get API from Dev Team,

1. Use Thread groups and feed the API url into HTTP request sample.
2. Get JAuth from DB. Enter JAuth key into HTTP Header manager.
3. Add Result in the thread group.
   send request.
   You can observe the results and responses and draw the conclusions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture mobile app traffic and simulate back-end calls using JMeter.

JMeter comes with a proxy server, You just have to configure JMeter proxy so that it can capture mobile traffic.

For more information on Mobile Performance testing with JMeter please refer to this article.

[Mobile Performance Testing](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/07/jmeter-mobile-performance-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, we can have multiple logins on same mobile but don't know how.
Just [check this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl) its an android app and you can use multiple accounts in parallel in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a tool, then spent a bunch of time to tweak it to simulate different devices when you can create a small piece of code to do the same ?

With most higher level languages you can create REST calls (I assume that this is what is used between the app and the server) in minutes, still be flexible and most important from testing side be able to inspect the process.

Take for example Python, you can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) to simulate a login in 10 lines of code, including printing the results

Answer (score 0):

You can record your mobile application network activity using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building)

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click start
2. Prepare your mobile device for recording.

   - Install `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file onto your mobile device (the file lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
   - Configure your mobile device to use JMeter as a proxy
3. Execute your scenario on the mobile device
4. JMeter should capture requests and store them under [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

See [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) article for detailed step-by-step instructions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To your second question, you can also use **Gatling** which uses **scala** as programming language to do multiple simultaneous logins via mobile api. It is very much effective and customization can be applied to your needs.

They provide suitable reports to watch the results with stats which comes handy.